# If $\lambda$ is not a eigenvalue of $H$ then the ODE $x'=Hx+e^{\lambda t }p$ has a solution $\phi(t)=e^{\lambda t}v$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have some troubles trying to prove this statement. If $\lambda$  is not a eigenvalue of $H$ then the ODE $x'=Hx+e^{\lambda t }p$ for each $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ has a solution of the form $\phi(t)=e^{\lambda t}v$ for some $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

My attemps.

Suppose $\phi(t)=e^{\lambda t}v$ is a solution of the ODE for some $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then

$$ \lambda e^{\lambda t}v=He^{\lambda t }v+e^{\lambda t}p$$
$$  \Longrightarrow \lambda v = Hv+p$$
$$\Longrightarrow (\lambda-H) v =p$$

But i can't infer anything from the last equality. Can somebody give me a hand?

Comment: @Aryadeva but this is not the case. $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $H$, of course that means that $Hv\neq\lambda v$.

Comment: @Aryadeva this is not relevant. In fact, I want to show how is defined such $v$.

Comment: Well  $p,H,\lambda $ are given by the differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final equality should be
$$
\left( \lambda I - H \right) v = p, $$
where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.  Then, as correctly noted in the comments, since $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $H$, it follows that
$\det \left( \lambda I - H \right) \neq 0,  $ so there exists a matrix
$$ A = \left( \lambda I - H \right)^{-1}. $$
Since $p$ and $\lambda $ are both known, this is sufficient to find $v$.